# What is the best way to decline an interview after applying for it?

Tags: career-path, professorship, postdocs, interview

I have applied to 2 postdoc jobs in the same university and have been selected for a 2nd interview in one before doing the first interview in the other lab.

The interviews are set at different times and so I will not be able to attend both so I wish to cancel the one where I haven't been yet. Should I say to the professor the truth "I will be interviewing with another lab" or shall I just say that for some reason I have to cancel it without mentioning the other interview?

Comment: Have you considered simply asking to reschedule the interview?  But if you really want to cancel, you can always say something vague like "I'm pursuing other opportunities".

Comment: +1 for @Nate = ask to reschedule if you're interested in the job.  Otherwise, you don't even need to say "I'm pursuing other opportunities".  Just give as much notice as possible (to maximise the chance they can invite someone else etc), give a brief apology for the inconvenience (if you are indeed sorry :)), thank them for considering your application.  Done.

Comment: If they are at different times, why can't you attend both?

Comment: The OP's language is confusing. I'm assuming that "interviews are set at different times and I will not be able to attend both" means that both interviews were set on the same date, but at different times (and of course different locations). So the solution is to change the date.

Comment: @Karen That makes no sense to me, unless the interviews are in (relatively) quick succession. If they are on the same day but at (vastly) different hours that would be beneficial, as only one trip will be required to do both.  On topic though: It's not the prof's business that you have a meeting with another one. Both are separate things.

Comment: Actually I will be coming from Japan for the interview and can't make many trips to Europe and the interview can also not be reschedule during the time I will be in EU (prof away) so that is why I should cancel it.

Answer (score 15):

Title
Name
Address

Dear University B -

Thank you very much for notifying me that I am on the short list for position W at University B and for scheduling me for a first-round interview on February X, 2015.

I have recently been notified by University A that I am a finalist for a position at Lab A and they want to schedule a second-round interview, also on February X, 2015.

As the Lab A request is for a second-round interview, I feel that I must prioritize this against first-rounds, even though I am still very much interested in pursuing the position at your lab.

Would it be possible for us to reschedule my interview for Feb (X-7)?  I understand that this may raise logistical concerns and appreciate your consideration.

Sincerely,

User34154

Comment: Absolutely this.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that the interviews are at different times, so it would require two visits to the same university. I still like your answer.

Answer (score 4):

tell the truth, as you haven't done anything unethical. however, just attending the interview is still a good solution.

Comment: +1, but you could capitalize your sentences and explain why the alternative is a good idea.